# Convert double to Int64 in swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios7, casting, primes

I'm a beginner to swift. I'm just trying out to write a program to print nth prime, but having some trouble converting sqrt function to int. Below is the code which works fine with c/c++.

```
func nthPrime(n: Int64)
    {
        var i:Int64=4,j:Int64=0, prime:Int64=0
        var count:Int64=0

        while count != n
        {

            for (j=2 ; j < Int64((sqrt(i))) + 1 ; j++) //Shows error cant invoke init with argument list of type (@lvalue Int64,$T9)
            {
                if(i%j == 0)
                {
                    i++
                    break
                }
                else if(j == Int64(sqrt(i)))
                {
                    count++
                    i++
                }
            }


        }

        println("\(n)th prime is \(prime)")
    }
```

Is it possible to do this kind of comparison in swift? I know if I change the var i and j to Double it will remove the error but the code wont work properly. Any other suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sqrt method input parameter needs to be a Double. So you need to cast it to Double. You will also need to use the math method called ceil.

> In mathematics and computer science, the floor and ceiling functions
>   map a real number to the largest previous or the smallest following
>   integer, respectively.

It will result in a Double so you need to convert the result back to Integer again. Try using it like this:

```
Int(ceil(sqrt(Double(i))))
```

//

```
extension Int {
    var isPrime:Bool{
        if self <  2 { return false }
        let squareRoot = Int(sqrt(Double(self)))
        if squareRoot * squareRoot == self { return false }
        for i in 2..<Int(ceil(sqrt(Double(self)))) {
            if self % i == 0 { return false }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

//

```
1.isPrime   // false
2.isPrime   // true
3.isPrime   // true
4.isPrime   // false
5.isPrime   // true
6.isPrime   // false
7.isPrime   // true
8.isPrime   // false
9.isPrime   // false
10.isPrime   // false
11.isPrime   // true
```

//

```
let myInt = 7

if myInt.isPrime {
    // do this
} else {
    // do that
}
```

//

```
var twoDigitsPrimeNumbers:[Int] = []
for number in 1..<100 {
    if number.isPrime {
        twoDigitsPrimeNumbers.append(number)
    }
}
println(twoDigitsPrimeNumbers.description)  // [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]

func nthPrime(nth:Int)-> Int {
    var primeCounter = 0
    var number = 2
    while true {
        if number.isPrime {
            primeCounter++
            if nth == primeCounter { return number}
        }
        number++
    }
}
nthPrime(1000)   // 7,919
```